# How can call custom class in a fragment's onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can i call a custom class in onOptionsItemSelected method. I have fragments and some fragments has different actionbars items. I don't want to write same code `item.getItemId()` over and over again.I wrote a class about for action bar selected items.It is not working. How can i call custom class and method?

```
public class ActionMenuItemSelected {
    public Fragment actionMenuSelectedItem(MenuItem item) {
        Fragment selected_fragment = null;
        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_menu_Resmece:
                selected_fragment = new MainFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.action_menu_account:
                selected_fragment = new AccountFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.action_level_about_us:
                selected_fragment = new AboutUsFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.action_level_contact_us:
                selected_fragment = new ContactUsFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.action_menu_log_out:
                mAuth.signOut();
                selected_fragment = new RegisterFragment();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        return selected_fragment;


    }
    //region goToFragment
    public void goToFragment(Fragment selectFragment) {
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getContext();

        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frame, selectFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }
//endregion
}
```

I added a class name ActionMenuItemSelected and i want to call this method in a fragment's onOptionsItemSelected method. I couldn't do it. Would you help me for calling this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity you need to inflate a menu layout

```
//Add this method to your activity
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); // Inflate your menu
    return true;
}
```

After setup a menu layout you can call your custom class

`private final ActionMenuItemSelected amis = new ActionMenuItemSelected();`

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {        
    Fragment frag = amis.actionMenuSelectedItem(item);
    goToFragment(frag); // assuming that this method is in your class Activity 
    return true;
}
```

But if in your App only one Activity has this menu setup you can put all `ActionMenuItemSelected.actionMenuSelectedItem`logic in your `onOptionsItemSelected(Menu item)` method.

Don't forget to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in onCreate() method if you are in a Fragment